# C++ Create variable only if template argument is true

Tags: c++, templates

Is there a way to create a variable in the function only if a template argument is true?

```
template<bool _CalcExtra>
int foo()
{
    int local;
    int local2;

    for(work)
    {
        ... work using local
        if(_CalcExtra)
            ... additional work using local and local2
    }

    if(_CalcExtra)   
        return local2;
    return local;
}
```

I am assuming most compilers will just remove local2 when the function is called like this

```
foo<false>();
```

but is there a programmatic way to make sure local2 is never allocated?

Comment: It's worth noting that compilers are REALLY good at not allocating variables that are not actually used, so I would double check that you actually need this before butchering your code for potentially no benefit.

Comment: do not try to outsmart your copiler, it will do the necessary optimization for you anyway. focus on writing clean readable code

Comment: If you don't use local2, the compiler won't bother allocating space for it. The example is not clear enough to understand exactly your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, it's not guaranteed that *either* `local` or `local2` are allocated, at least in the sense of being given a memory location. Compilers often use CPU registers to store local variables, and compilers only assign variables to a regsiter when

- they're assigned a value
- the code uses them in some way

Unused variables are often elided completely, and the compiler doesn't produce any assembly corresponding to them.

The only exception to this is if a variable's constructor has some side-effect which might be visible (for example, if it opens a file or prints something out when constructed).

That being said, you can conditionally ensure that the compiler doesn't produce any assembly corresponding to `local2`, *even in debug mode*, by using an `if constexpr` statement (introducd in C++17):

```
template<bool _CalcExtra>
int foo()
{
    int local;

    if constexpr(_CalcExtra) {
        int local2;

        for(...)
        {
            ... work using local
            ... additional work using local and local2
        }

        return local2; 
    } else {
        for(...)
        {
            ... work using local
        }

        return local; 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

There is no (standard) way to know what variables will be allocated on the stack, what will be only put on registers and what will just be discarded. Temporaries may also be spilled on the stack.

Here, it is a trivial optimization to delete these branches. You could use `if constexpr` to ensure it is.

You could also look at the generated assembly code to look at what is allocated or not.

In an extreme case, you might want to specialize you function manually on the value of the parameter, and only using `local2` in the `false` specialization.

Note that allocations on the stack are free outside of stack space usage... It's just moving the stack pointer 4 bytes more when entering the function.

Comment: Yeah, I had that idea. Then the OP updated the question in a way that completely invalidated this approach. You should re-read the question for the update.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up !